# current transformer and its connections to the microcntroller(8051)

Tags: current, transformer

i want to make an anti power theft system to a digital meter,for that purpose  i am first trying to make digital meter to  measure how much power is being used in our house.

So i want to measure current in the line being drawn when any devices are on ( i.e instantaneous current), I have planned to use current transformer but, before going to the question i would like to ask that same job of  the current transformer  can be done using a power resistor then why not to use that??

ok if that is being answered then :i am actually going to measure the voltage  across c/t or the resistor but i am stuck  at this  point  how  to  find  the  voltage??.

Actually  i  wanted  to use differential  op-amp circuit  which could measure exactly the voltage difference  across the  resistor/ c/t and could  be  fed  to  the  adc.
 But  the input  is ac if i opt for rectification &  various other  procedures then  there will be  lot  of  stuff  to  be included  and the signal  will attenuate..
so  can  any one  suggest  whether  that idea   of using differential  opamp  is right??...and how  should signal be maintained?

Comment: Please edit the question to break the block of text into paragraphs, for readability. An empty line between paragraphs shows up as a paragraph break.

Comment: i have edited it can u read now? & give me an answer to the question?

Answer (score 2):

You may use a resistor + an OPA to measure the AC current. However, there are a few things that make this less desirable:

- a resistor + an OPA is not galvanically isolated (the current transformer is),
- the power lost on the resistor will limit how large signals you can get, and the offset voltage of the OPA will limit how small signals you can detect - these two together will limit the usable range of your measurements (the current transformer can amplify the signal level, and still represent only a very little load to the circuit to be measured).

If I were you, I'd use a current transformer, and some specialized IC (like the ADE7753 and its relatives). See this project: http://www.delorie.com/electronics/powermeter/

Comment: please can u tell me detailed information about current transformer.i searched it on website but didn't find good enough information

Comment: Here is a complete design for you: [AN-679 from Analog Devices](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/application_notes/AN-679.pdf)